# Is value in array column in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to generate a boolean column that evaluates whether a value (e.g. `1`) is in an array (e.g. `[1,2]`) for each row of my table. **My question is: what is the best way to do this?**

As I understand, all elements of an `ARRAY` in Snowflake are of type `VARIANT`. These demonstrate the options I'm working with. I'm personally trying to figure out how to see if the value in a `NUMBER` column is an element of the `ARRAY` column.

**Example**

```
WITH example_cte AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(1 AS VARIANT) one_as_variant,
        CAST('1' AS VARIANT) string_one_as_variant,
        CAST(CAST(1 AS VARCHAR) AS VARIANT) as one_as_varchar_then_variant,
        [ '2', '1' ] AS my_array
)
SELECT
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(one_as_variant, my_array) as one_as_variant_is_in_array, -- evaluates as FALSE
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(string_one_as_variant, my_array) as string_one_as_variant_is_in_array, -- evaluates as TRUE
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(one_as_varchar_then_variant, my_array) as one_as_varchar_then_variant_is_in_array -- evaluates as TRUE
FROM
    example_cte;
```

Comment: use `(1,2)` as my_arrays, your array consists of varchar so only varchar can match the content

Comment: If I could, I would! This is a column that is already defined for me. Is there a simple way to convert?

Comment: your one_as_varchar_then_variant is the best chance, but converting costs time

Comment: Why not just use the ARRAY_CONTAINS function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the variant "have a type", and thus string are not number, and making an array of numbers, fails for the strings, but passes for the numbers:

```
SELECT
    1::VARIANT as v1_n,
    '1'::VARIANT as v1_s,
    1::VARCHAR::VARIANT as v1_n_s,
    array_construct('2', '1') as a1,
    array_construct(2, 1) as a2,
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(v1_n, a1) as a1_contains_v1_n,
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(v1_s, a1) as a1_contains_v1_s,
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(v1_n_s, a1) as a1_contains_v1_n_s,
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(v1_n, a2) as a2_contains_v1_n,
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(v1_s, a2) as a2_contains_v1_s,
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(v1_n_s, a2) as a2_contains_v1_n_s
```

| V1_N | V1_S | V1_N_S | A1 | A2 | A1_CONTAINS_V1_N | A1_CONTAINS_V1_S | A1_CONTAINS_V1_N_S | A2_CONTAINS_V1_N | A2_CONTAINS_V1_S | A2_CONTAINS_V1_N_S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "1" | "1" | [ "2", "1" ] | [ 2, 1 ] | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |

so then if we ask what the types are:

```
SELECT
    1::VARIANT as v1_n,
    TYPEOF(v1_n) as t_v1_n,
    '1'::VARIANT as v1_s,
    TYPEOF(v1_s) as t_v1_s,
    1::VARCHAR::VARIANT as v1_n_s,
    TYPEOF(v1_n_s) as t_v1_n_s,
    array_construct('2', '1') as a1,
    TYPEOF(a1[0]) as t_a1_0,
    array_construct(2, 1) as a2,
    TYPEOF(a2[0]) as t_a2_0
```

| col | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| V1_N | 1 | INTEGER |
| V1_S | "1" | VARCHAR |
| V1_N_S | "1" | VARCHAR |
| A1 | [ "2", "1" ] | VARCHAR |
| A2 | [ 2, 1 ] | INTEGER |

so how to get around this?

If you array have mixed types, you will have to rebuild them, but then you can know what to cast your values to.

OR if you know the type of array is always strings, like in your example, you can just cast the values:

```
SELECT
    1::VARIANT as v1_n,
    '1'::VARIANT as v1_s,
    1::VARCHAR::VARIANT as v1_n_s,
    array_construct('2', '1') as a1,
    array_contains(v1_n::text::variant, a1) as c_v1_n,    
    array_contains(v1_s::text::variant, a1) as c_v1_s,   
    array_contains(v1_n_s::text::variant, a1) as c_v1_n_s
```

| V1_N | V1_S | V1_N_S | A1 | C_V1_N | C_V1_S | C_V1_N_S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "1" | "1" | [ "2", "1" ] | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |